# make a label from a Button in kivy ,kv file

Tags: python, module, kivy, kivy-language, python-3.8

ok, look can anyone give an example in kivy .kv file of a button that is set to a command that when you press it,it will make a label beneath the button,
I attempted this

python

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyLayout(Widget,App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def addthelabel(self):
        self.button = Label(text"you have just added me")
        self.add_widget(self.button)
class UiApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyLayout()
UiApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"horizontal"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            text:"hello"
            on_press:
            root.addthelabel()
```

but when I ran it and clicked the button it's not what I expected
IMAGE
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoOCj.png
so I need a fresh example can you guys help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behaviour is because in `addthelabel()`, the new `Label` is being added as a child of the root `MyWidget` layout, rather than to the `BoxLayout` that contains the existing button.

To get the behaviour you want you need to add an `id` to the `BoxLayout` in the `kv` file that allows you to access that widget from the Python code. You also need to change the `orientation` to `vertical`.

```
<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: layout
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            text:"hello"
            on_press: root.addthelabel()
```

Then in the Python code, instead of adding the new `Label` to the root widget, we want to add it to the `BoxLayout` using its new `id`

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyLayout(Widget,App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def addthelabel(self):
        self.button = Label(text="you have just added me")
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(self.button)
class UiApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyLayout()
UiApp().run()
```